# How to render an element whose id is automatically generated in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have primefaces'datatable placed on primefaces tabView..

I m using filtering on it. As new values are updated in the grid, I want to re-render the filters.

The filter id is generated as: tabViewId:ActiveTabIndex:DatatableID:ColumnName_filter.

On value change of input text, I want to re-render the filter.

```
<p:column width="40">
                    <h:inputText id="vendorInputTxt" value="#{articlePromo.proveedor}"
                        styleClass="inputTextStyle">
                        <f:ajax event="change" render=":categoryTabView:0:promotionDetail_dataTable:vendorColumnHeader_filter"
                            listener="#{promotionDetailManagedBean.onProveedorChange}" />
                    </h:inputText>
                </p:column>
```

But it gives the error,  **contains an unknown id ':categoryTabView:0:promotionDetail_dataTable:vendorColumnHeader_filter' - cannot locate it in the context of the component vendorInputTxt**

What is the right way to render the filter again?

Thanks,
Shikha

Answer (score 0):

try a js call oncomplete to: `widget_<dataTableId>.filter();`  where the dataTableId is the id given to the dataTable.

Comment: better approach is to assign `widgetVar` attribute to `p:dataTable` and call `.filter()` on it.

Comment: @Fallup I agree.  It is the cleaner and proper approach.

Comment: <f:ajax> does not have "oncomplete" attribute in jsf2. Pls correct me if I'm wrong. I didn't find it in documentation. Tried running is as well. But, I guess, attribute is not there.

Comment: Try [p:ajax](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/index.html?p/ajax.html) instead.

Comment: Oh yea I totally forgot, `p:ajax` does have `oncomplete` so you can bind `dataTablesWidgetVar.filter()` to its oncomplete.

Comment: widgetVar attribute of dattable --> "dataTableWidget"   `code` <h:inputText id="originalCostInputTxt"
      value="#{articlePromo.costoBruto}"
      onchange="onSuggestedValueChange(this)">
      <p:ajax event="change" oncomplete="getFilter(dataTableWidget)"
       listener="#{promotionDetailManagedBean.onCostoBrutoChange}" />
     </h:inputText> `code`   Javascript: `code` function getFilter(dataTableWidget){
 dataTableWidget.filter();
} `code`  . Java script is breaking in getFilter method.  Whats incorrect in this ?

Comment: Why getFilter()?  try the following... `<p:ajax event="change" oncomplete="dataTableWidget.filter();" listener="#{promotionDetailManagedBean.onCostoBrutoChange}" />`