# how to update the filter of dataTable - Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I have an editable datatable.

The filter of the columns is binded to an array of type selectItem.

Since the datatable is editable, the value can be updated. the requirement is to update the filter when value in the corresponding column changes.

I could achieve the same by re-rendering the datatable.

Can the filters be updated when any value in the column changes without re-rendering the dataTable?

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: I believe you asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119518/how-to-render-an-element-whose-id-is-automatically-generated-in-jsf) as well.

Comment: Things are similar but different. Here, my question was how to update without re-rendering. There, my concern was I am not able to catch any component in the render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the same by manipulating the filter by javascript.

The id of the filter is generated as: _filter

```
<select id="columnId_filter"></select>
```

This is how we can manipulate the option:

```
var selectexample = document.getElementById("columnId_filter");
selectexample.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');
```